# Get cryptic error when trying to create a snapshot of any of my VMs

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox. I have 6 VMs that I've imported. When I click on an individual VM, and then click the camera image (or Ctrl+Shift+S) to take a snapshot, the snapshot process fails and VirtualBox gives the following error:

```
Failed to create a snapshot of the virtual machine vmName.
```

Details:

```
Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
```

This happens not only for one of my VMs, but all of them, if I try to take a snapshot of each one separately, one at a time.

My computer is a Windows 7 machine. I have 200 GB free on my hard drive, and I see no reason why the error should occur. I can import VMs, run them, and clone then without any problems.

Can anyone tell me what to do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see what the problem was.

I was saving the snapshot to here:

```
D:\Virtual machines\SPM\Snapshots
```

This is my DVD drive. For some reason VirtualBox was defaulting to this location. Simply changing the location fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to write snapshots to a location that is not writable (or doesn't exist). This setting is imported with the VM, so it is likely that the location existed on the host where the VM was created, but does not exist on your host.

To check/fix it:

1. Shut down or power off the VM
2. Open the *Settings* window
3. Go to the *General* section and click on the *Advanced* tab
4. Make sure *Snapshot Folder* is set to a folder that exists and is writable
5. Close the *Settings* dialog
6. Take a snapshot